# Automating Multi select drop down(optgroup)

Tags: javascript, php, selenium, multi-select, optgroup

I am trying to automate the selection of a value from the drop down that supports multi select using selenium. I find an issue as the dropdown is not a traditional one and manually selecting a value will show in another field as selected values.

It is a third party tool(optgroup as mentioned by the developer).

The drop down looks this way
[Drop down image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IULiw.png)

Following is the HTML content of the drop down

```
<div class="multiSelectOptions" style="position: absolute; z-index: 99999; visibility: visible; height: 150px; width: 203px; top: 958px; left: 398px;">
<label class="cl_Mlslt_emp_id" style="background-color:#FEF4DA;font-weight:bold;color:black;">Search: 
    <input type="textbox" class="comn-input" size="18" style="height:12px;margin:3px 0 2px 0;" onkeyup="searchTextInMultiDropDown(this);" id="srch_Mlslt_emp_id" name="srch_Mlslt_emp_id">
</label>
<label style="height:1px;background-color:#CCCCCC;margin-top:2px;">
</label>
<label class="selectAll">
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll">Remove All</label>
<label class="optGroup">My Team</label>
<label class="lbl_Mlslt_emp_id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Mlslt_emp_id[]" value="1" class="formpref">
        <span>Emp 1</span>
</label>
<label class="lbl_Mlslt_emp_id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Mlslt_emp_id[]" value="2" class="formpref">
        <span>Emp 2</span>
</label>
<label class="optGroup">Other Team</label>
<label class="lbl_Mlslt_emp_id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Mlslt_emp_id[]" value="3" class="formpref">
        <span>Other Emp 1</span>
</label>
<label class="lbl_Mlslt_emp_id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Mlslt_emp_id[]" value="4" class="formpref">
        <span>Other Emp 2</span>
</label>
<label class="lbl_Mlslt_emp_id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Mlslt_emp_id[]" value="5" class="formpref">
        <span>Other Emp 3</span>
</label>
<label class="lbl_Mlslt_emp_id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Mlslt_emp_id[]" value="6" class="formpref">
        <span>Other Emp 4</span>
</label>
<label class="lbl_Mlslt_emp_id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Mlslt_emp_id[]" value="7" class="formpref">
        <span>Other Emp 5</span>
</label>
</div>
```